# <span> button not working inside header class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a hamburger button in order to show sidebar in my HTML file using JS. Basically it's a code snippet of a `<div>`, a small JS code, and a `<span>` class containing the actual hamburger. What I wanted to do was to put the hamburger button (it's not defined by button class though) inline with the header. I managed to do that but for some reason that button is not working now. Can someone please tell me why is that so? And if there is any other way to put the button inline with the header class?

```css
/*CSS for header:*/

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 90%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  font-family: "Operator SSm A", "Operator SSm B", monospace;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/*CSS for hamburger menu:*/

.overlay-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

```html
<header class="header" style="width:100%" id="header">
  <div class="loading"></div>
  <div id="index" class="overlay-nav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn-nav" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-nav-content">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About Us</a>
      <a href="#">Sessions</a>
      <a href="#">Competitions</a>
      <a href="#">Meetings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span style="font-size:20px; cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>
  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("index").style.width = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("index").style.width = "0%";
    }
  </script>

  <div class="header__logo">
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
```

P.S Is it happening because the pointer events is set to none?

Comment: Yes, pointer-events: none will block the click event from occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is because you're using `pointer-events: none`, which disables any events caused by the mouse. Perhaps you mean to use `pointer: none` to get rid of any pointers.

Also, I'm not sure the reason you have `opacity: 0` on your `.header` class, but that is hiding the button from even being visible.

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer-events: none stopping click event and you have applied opacity:0 to header so it is not displaying , First of all remove `pointer-events: none;` and `opacity:1`

```css
/*CSS for header:*/

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 90%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  font-family: "Operator SSm A", "Operator SSm B", monospace;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 10px;
  pointer-events:all;
}

.closebtn-nav{
  color:#ffffff;
}

/*CSS for hamburger menu:*/

.overlay-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

```html
<script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("index").style.width = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("index").style.width = "0%";
    }
  </script>

<header class="header" style="width:100%" id="header">
  <div class="loading"></div>
  <div id="index" class="overlay-nav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn-nav" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-nav-content">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About Us</a>
      <a href="#">Sessions</a>
      <a href="#">Competitions</a>
      <a href="#">Meetings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span style="font-size:20px; cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>


  <div class="header__logo">
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Make sure you also explain what the problem was :)